# Is there an elegant way to integrate code performing authentication on other php site into Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization

I am developing Rails application, in which I need to authorize users from other site written on PHP.

The APIs of PHP site written by its developer are custom i.e. they are not OmniAuth or similar.

I wonder, if there is elegant way to somehow integrate my code sending/receiving JSON responses to/from PHP site into Devise, so it could work like I am doing authentication of users in usual Devise way from my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to official answer, I got from Devise maintainers: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/plataformatec-devise/lB4e0nYiM_U/RPDReqjO67QJ. Which means, the short answer is NO.